# Como faço para ter o mesmo response do navegador usando java/socket?

Tags: java, socket, post, request, http-post

É o seguinte, alguém já precisou fazer um request `http-post` implementando `socket` em java?

Eu preciso fazer um request no site `http://spys.ru/en/` e pegar o response para minerar alguns proxys.Porém, não consigo trazer o mesmo response que consigo no chrome nem com o gabiroto, sempre vem um `gap` de informações!.

Lembrando que o requisito é usar `SOCKET` ou seja, não posso usar nenhuma derivada desse cara, mesmo que ele use `socket`.

```
try {
        // Construct data
        String data = URLEncoder
                .encode("tldc=0&eport=8080&anmm=0&vlast=0&submit=Proxy+search",
                        "UTF-8");

        s = new Socket("spys.ru", 80);

        // Send headers
        wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(),
                "UTF8"));
        wr.write("POST /en/ HTTP/1.0\r\n");

        wr.write("Host: spys.ru\r\n");
        wr.write("Connection: keep-alive\r\n");
        wr.write("Content-Length: " + data.length() + "\r\n");
        wr.write("Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n");
        wr.write("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n");
        wr.write("Origin: http://spys.ru\r\n");
        wr.write("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36\r\n");
        wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        wr.write("Referer: http://spys.ru/en/\r\n");
        wr.write("Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\r\n");

        wr.write("\r\n");

        // Send parameters
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        // Get response
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String line;



        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);                           
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            s.close();
            wr.close();
            rd.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aparentemente os campos estao corretos. O que está sendo retornado? O que pode estar dando problema é você não usar `chunked` ao receber os dados (não testei se funciona em HTTP 1.0).

Comment: Acabo de testar aqui, mesmo sem setar nenhum dos headers, veio a lista toda, na linha 101 ou 102 do HTML. PS: Não testei em java, usei outra linguagem. Mas vem todos os dados tranquilamente, sem precisar de nenhum malabarismo.

Comment: é o seguinte, eu preciso dar um "proxy search" e passar os parametros do post. Então, acho que vou precisar fazer um get nessa página, armazenar o cookie e depois mandar um post com os parametros.

Comment: Aqui nao precisou de nada disso, só fiz a requisição com `tldc=0&eport=8080&anmm=0&vlast=0&submit=Proxy+search` e os resultados vieram tranquilamente. Nem precisei simular os cabeçalhos do browser.

Comment: Tem certeza que vc está analisando o retorno corretamente?